# Triggering a target when a service stops in systemd

Tags: centos7, systemd

I have a situation where I'm using systemd in an environment where I have a main application that should be launched at start up and when the application exits shutdown should start.

I've created target and service files that cause the application to launch on start up however I can't see how to trigger the shutdown when the file exits cleanly.

Comment: Use [PartOf=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PartOf=)